# yml config about http and https

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

In `application.yml`, I need to config https port and http port.

For this, code is as follows in `application.properties`.

```
server.port.http=80
server.port.https=443
```

In `application.yml`, I tried follwing code for configuration,
but it doesn't work.

code1

```
server:
  port: 443
    http: 80
```

code2

```
server:
  port:
    http: 80
  port: 443
```

How do this only with `application.yml`?
I can do it with collaboration of `.properties` and `.yml`.
However, I want to do this with only `application.yml`.

---

## Solution

I found solution thanks to answer of `dariosicily`.

I configured https and http port as follows.

```
server:
  port: 443
  ports:
    https: 443
    http: 8080
```

I need to configure default port of spring boot.
So, I configured default port using `server.port=443`,
and https and http port using `server.ports`.

And used them in java as follows.

```
@Value("${server.ports.http}")
private int serverPortHttp;

@Value("${server.ports.https}")
private int serverPortHttps;
```

It works really well. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure both http and https ports creating a dictionary with *http* and *https* keys in your `application.yml` :

```
server:
  port: 
      http: 8080
      https: 443
```

Then you can access both properties in your java class (or kotlin with an equivalent code) :

```
@Value("${server.port.http}")
private int httpPort;
    
@Value("${server.port.https}")
private int httpsPort;
```